# Reporting memory usage per process/program

Tags: unix, memory, performance-monitoring

How can I get the current memory usage for all running processes individually?  Preferably in bytes so they can be added up accurately.  Can I roll up the summaries for child processes into the process that spawned them?  (e.g all apache threads together).

Sometimes, my server runs out of memory and becomes unresponsive.  I want to discover what is using up all the memory.  Unfortunately, it's likely to not be a single process.  Some programs spawn hundreds of processes, each using very little memory, but it adds up.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you part of the way there:

```
ps axfo %mem,size,rss,vsz,pid,args
```

By the way, Apache is probably preforked instead of threaded.

Comment: Cool command.  Yes, it's prefork.  Unfortunately, the httpd processes come out a little chaotic, none of them grouped under the process that started them.  pstree doesn't group them either.  Best I can do is to group them by name.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux
```

There is a column called RSS, which is the non-swapped memory usage in kilobytes.  I had to parse the output of this command and add it up myself to find out the total per command name.

Answer (score 1):

I present [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/), which introduces the concept of *Proportional Set Size*:

> Because large portions of physical memory are typically shared among multiple applications, the standard measure of memory usage known as resident set size (RSS) will significantly overestimate memory usage. PSS instead measures each application's "fair share" of each shared area to give a realistic measure.

Alternatively, you can just look for oomkiller logs, it'll tell you what program got killed for breaking the camel's back in memory allocation.

Comment: Cool info.  I don't have this command though.

Comment: The website comes with source code, dude.

Answer (score 0):

You do not tell what Unix you are running. If it is Solaris, you can use the prstat command which have some useful options, like:

```
prstat -s rss -a # sorted by RAM usage, per user metrics
```

Comment: I didn't mention it because it's CentOS :P